# Python: Sorting and printing data correctly from a txt file

Tags: python, sorting

My task is to create a code which is a quiz for students. It also enables teachers to see how well a student has done compared to the rest of the class. Once the student has completed the quiz, its 'username' and 'correct_answers' is stored onto the text file (the part of my code that actually works). I've managed to prevent my code from creating a new username each time the same student retakes the test. Everything stated above happens when the user selects 'if status == 1:'. (status 1 is for students while status 2 is for teachers).

When status 2 is selected, the teacher is asked what class they would like to view. After one has been selected, the 3 latest scores and username should be sorted:

1. in alphabetical order with each students highest score for the test
2. by the highest score, highest to lowest
3. by the average score, highest to lowest

This is what I have come up with for status 2 so far:

```
elif status == 2:
while True:
    try:
        users_class2 = int(input("Which class would you like to view? (1,2 or 3)"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number!")
    else:
        if users_class2 not in {1,2,3}:
            print("Please enter a number in {1,2,3}!")
        else:
            break

if users_class2 == 1:
    val=[]
    keys=[]
    i=0
    l=[]
    lines=open('class1.txt','r').readlines()
    for line in lines:
      try:
        val.append(int(line))
      except:
        keys.append(line)

    for i in range(0,len(val),3):
     h=val[i:i+3]
     h.sort()
     l.append(h[::-1])
    print ("Sort the test results alphabetically and show the students highest score.\n")
    for i,j in zip(keys,l):
        print ("{},{}".format(i,j))

    print ("Sort by the average score, highest to lowest.")
    avlist=[float(sum(i))/len(i) for i in l ]
    print ("{}".format(avlist))
    while(len(avlist)):
        for i,j in zip(keys,avlist):
            if j==max(avlist):
              print ("{},{}".format(i,j))
              avlist.remove(j)

    print ("'\nSort by the highest score, highest to lowest.\n")
    hlist=[max(i) for i in l ]
    hlist.sort()
    hlist=hlist[::-1]
    for k in hlist:
        for i,j in zip(keys,l):
            if max(j)==k:
                print ("{},{}".format(i,j))
```

The code above only shows one if statement which is for 'users_class2'. This is repeated 2 more times for 'class2.txt' and 'class3.txt'.

After a class has been selected, my code should output something like:

> Sorted the test results alphabetically and shows the students highestscore.

Alan,8,7,8

Bob,9,9,8

Charlie,3,4,5

> Sort by the average score, highest to lowest.

Bob,9,9,8

Alan,8,7,8

Charlie,3,4,5

> Sort by the highest score, highest to lowest.

Bob,9,9,8

Alan,8,7,8

Charlie,3,4,5

But instead I get:

> Sort the test results alphabetically and show the students highest score.
>
> Sort by the average score, highest to lowest.

[] '

> Sort by the highest score, highest to lowest.

I've been working on this for quite some time now but with no luck. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me find a fix for this. If you see any areas where I could make my code for efficient please say so. Thanks.

Comment: First line of your code here is `elif status == 2:`? I seems something is missing as it cant be a first line of your code.

Comment: @Marcin OP said this is an extract, obviously the first section of the code is `if status ==1:` for the student

Comment: using `lines=open('class1.txt','r').readlines()` you may be throwing away the file handle you need to close the file at the end of the operation. You could use the `with` statement to remove the need to close the file or capture the return value from `open` and call `close` on it. For details see the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: To take some of the guess work out of this could you include a simple class1.txt in the question or explain its format?

Comment: What is the format of your `class#.txt` files?

Comment: Its 'username', 'user_score, 'user_score', 'user_score'

Comment: then its the next line

Answer (score -1):

> if users_class2 not in {1,2,3}:

should really be

> if users_class2 not in [1,2,3]:

Try to print out what val and keys are, are they printing out the data as you expected?

---

So from your code it appears that you are trying to read from a text file, and then adding them to `keys` and `val`, right?

You can try adding these statements for debugging purpose to see if 'val' was getting populated as expected:

```
print "val is"
print val
print "====="
```

You can add that right above this for loop perhaps `for i in range(0,len(val),3):`

Comment: Im sorry. I am quite new to coding. What do you mean by 'Try to print out what val and keys are'?

Comment: The one where you have suggested 'print val'

Comment: After adding a few brackets, this is returned: val is
[]
=====
val is
[]
=====

Comment: It's python 3 you need to use `print(val)`.

Comment: The suggestion to use `if users_class2 not in [1,2,3]` rather than the form with `{1, 2, 3}` is a bad one. In Python 3, the latter will be made into a constant `frozenset` which can be indexed very quickly. I suspect it doesn't matter much for such a short sequence, but the principal of the only concrete suggestion in this answer is flatly wrong.